Elasticsearch Nodes Tripped Numeric Value
Elasticsearch provides the Nodes Stats API for retrieving metrics for machines in a cluster. In the API, what does "tripped": ### mean?
I am running Elasticsearch 7.17.
I understand that tripping a circuit breaker means that some activity has caused JVM heap consumption in excess of limit_size.
What I would like to know is what does the numeric value of tripped mean. Also, it appears to be a monotonically increasing value. Is it ever reset to 0?
Example
GET /_nodes/stats/breaker/

    ...
                "parent": {
                    "limit_size_in_bytes": 30601641984,
                    "limit_size": "28.5gb",
                    "estimated_size_in_bytes": 29839003560,
                    "estimated_size": "27.7gb",
                    "overhead": 1.0,
                    "tripped": 5537236
                }

Reference
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/cluster-nodes-stats.html
